# Passing object from View to Controller using html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a viewModel object which I am planning to populate with data from an object passed to the controller via a form from the view. Currently this is what I have:

View

```
<form id="myForm" action="/Area/Controller/myAction" method="post">
                <input id="obj" type="hidden">
             </form>
```

Model

```
 public class myViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(myViewModel userInfo= null)
        {
            var model = MethodToFillInViewModel(userInfo);
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

The big picture here is I am trying to grab information from one page, pass it to the controller to pre-fill the view model, and then load "Index" with the fields pre-filled from the previous step. As of right now I am retrieving a null object and I am unsure why, can anyone please shed some light into this? (I am new to the whole MVC thing)

Comment: What type your Index view has?

Comment: *"I am new to the whole MVC thing"* - Honestly the best approach for you at this time would be to start with some introductory tutorials on the subject.  There are a couple of problems with the code you have.  (1) Your `<input>` has no `name` attribute, so its value will never be sent to the server.  (2) Your `<input>` can only have one of the two values in your view model.  You're probably also better off using the built-in HTML helpers instead of crafting your form inputs manually.  The latter can certainly work, and is fairly simple, but start by using the tools available to you.

Comment: ohk so you want the typed information from one page (and not save the data) then pass the information to another page? or you trying to do a simple Add and save the data then display that captured data in index page?or you want something else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag helpers:

```
@model myViewModel

<form id="myForm" asp-action="myAction" asp-controller="Area" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Email" type="hidden">
    <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: is the OP using core mvc?  He doesn't mention that anywhere in his post.